# How do I perform a standard erase on MacBook Pro Retina SSD?

Tags: disk-utility, ssd, filevault, data-recovery, secure-erase

An [archived Apple article](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201949) says: "Note: With an SSD drive, Secure Erase and Erasing Free Space are not available in Disk Utility. These options are not needed for an SSD drive because a **standard erase** makes it difficult to recover data from an SSD. For more security, consider turning on FileVault encryption when you start using your SSD drive."

Now the question is **what is standard erase and how do I perform it?**

If it is the *Erase* button shown at the top of Disk Utility, then that button is greyed out and not clickable. If the *Erase* button is greyed out because the *FileVault* is currently turned ON, how do I go about deactivating it and doing a standard erase on my SSD?

I just want to make sure that the data is non-recoverable before I give my Mac for repair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't perform an erase because you have booted from the SSD.  Hovering over the icon, will tell you why

[image]

To erase your SSD, boot from recovery or from a bootable USB then erase.  If you are sending it for repair, just create another admin account and delete your user profile.  It's much easier and just as secure.  The moment you finish deleting your files, they will become unrecoverable